# Trying to use a Query each loop on Raphael object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, raphael

I'm struggling trying to write a jQuery .each() function to loop though an array which I've built from a Raphael object. I can do it with a traditional JS for-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
 regions[i].node.setAttribute('fill', '#113381');
}
```

but when I try this:

```
$.each(regions, function (index) {
    $(this).node.setAttribute('fill', '#113381');
});
```

I get an error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$(this).node.setAttribute')

A typical array item looks like this:

```
var someName = rsr.path("M295.499,153.782l-0.77,4.605 l-5.786,1.016l-2.313-2.887l-1.233-3.278l-3.014-0.469l-3.39,1.013l-6.479,6.557l-5.575-0.332l-0.982-0.059l-3.936-2.262 l0.455-0.856l3.019-5.701l-1.623-1.325l2.408-4.141l11.51-0.261l5.212-0.119l-0.54,4.988l2.008,1.326l6.172-0.075L295.499,153.782z M274.037,160.428l2.193,1.402l5.325-5.342l-1.563-0.904L274.037,160.428z").attr({parent: 'someName',fill: '#CCCCCC',stroke: '#FFFFFF',"stroke-width": '0.54',"stroke-miterlimit": '10','stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('id', 'someName');
someName.attr({'id': 'someName','name': 'someName'});
regions.push(someName);
```

I've declared the array regions and it draws my Rapahel object.I would appreciate any help I can get. Many thanks.

Comment: Try without wrapping `this` in a jQuery function `this.node`. (There is no `node` method in jQuery is what it's complaining about). Or: `$.each(regions, function (el) { el.node.setAttribute('fill', '#113381');});`

Comment: @andy Thanks but that doesn't work. I still get an error - undefined is not an object

Comment: Ok, this appears to work: `$.each(regions, function (index) {

 this.node.setAttribute('fill', '#003300');
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no jQuery `node` method which is what you're attempting with this code:

```
$(this).node.setAttribute('fill', '#113381');
```

Instead use either:

```
$.each(regions, function (index, element) {
    element.node.setAttribute('fill', '#113381');
});
```

or:

```
$.each(regions, function (index, element) {
    this.node.setAttribute('fill', '#113381');
});
```